# Queries with calculated fields and sorting

Tags: azure-devops

We have started using queries in VSTS to find the projects with the highest value to facilitate a better planning structure and that works great but we also would like to measure that against a cost field. Ideally we would be calculating an ROI field that measures our value against cost and then sorts by ROI.

Is there no way to work with calculated fields in VSTS queries? We haven't been able to find anything so far. Any other workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not supported.

The workaround is that you can run a query with WIQL through [WIQL REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#run-a-query).

You can update the value in WIQL per to the stored query. (Get WIQL through [Queries REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#flat-query-with-expanded-clauses))

Comment: I see. So as far as I understand it you can run your own custom queries with calculated fields through this API but you wouldn't be able to have a calculated field displayed in VSTS even if you work through WIQL?